# Best efficient way to manage heavy files in android

Tags: android, multithreading, performance

I need some advice about manage many and large files in android (possibly in real time).
I've almost 6-7 images that comes from camera every second, I've to do some operation on each one and save it somewhere (about 1sec for image), then release/destroy the original.

Actually I use an ArrayBlockingQueue to save images when they comes and then processed asynchronously with a Thread. But there is a very big problem: each image is about 20MB so the RAM of the device become full very soon.

So I'm now looking for an more efficient way to store temporarily all these images and then process.. 
The best alternative I've thought is to store the images on the device (save only the path in queue) and then use the thread to process, but I don't know if is good as idea, I worried about the speed of the whole process.
Maybe a multithreading could help? If yes could someone link some good tutorial to understand well?

Thank you

**EDIT**

The best way I've found is to save on memory the frames (not in RAM), process with a thread and then delete the file.
Now the problem is that the process is too slow, so this could be solved by multi-threading.
Actually the whole queue is processed in this way:

```
                mBulbThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do stuff
        }
    };
```

what should I've to do to split this in two or three threads? The queue is unique, so should I've split the queue too?

Comment: No matter what you do multithreading or otherwise if you hold too many large Bitmaps in memory, the RAM usage WILL increase and cause `outofmemory` exception

Comment: If you want to process large Bitmap before you need set heapsize of your application is Large heap. That mean your app can use all free ram space in runtime when need. You should not use litle bitmap in sametime, i think you can process every bitmap with queue

Comment: Thank you for tips, I've already `android:largeHeap` to true, but the app still can't add more then 17 images to queue